# want to find the total of two columns in PHP

Tags: php, sql

[image]

Want to find the total of two or more table columns

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unclear.  What are you trying to total here?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and then `SUM(condition)` to obtain your counts:

```
SELECT   id AS ID,
     SUM(total     = 'total' ) AS Total,
FROM     table
GROUP BY ID
```

Something like this should work.